# Unable to close module dropdown of parent application on clicking anywhere in child application UI screen rendered in Ifaram

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, ember.js, parent-child

I am facing problem to close module dropdown on clicking anywhere in child application UI screen.
I am not be able to handle click Outside functionality for dropdown elements defined in Parent application after clicking on the `IFrame` which loads child application inside Parent application as I have an application built using Ember JS. Inside that I have another application plugin using IFrame created using React JS. I wanted to hide the rendered dropdown from the parent application by clicking inside the `IFrame` where the child application is presented.
Can anyone provide a solution to achieve it?